# Push rejected while deploying on heroku

Tags: python, git

I am deploying my project with heroku. My Django version number is 3.2.8 and python 3.9.7. It is written on heroku. Heroku supports Python 3.9.7 deployment, but there is an error in my push process. The version above does not support it. What should I do? Thank you for your reply
This is my cmd
[image]
my requirements.txt

[image]

Comment: Your requirements.txt says Python-3.7.2

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I still can't push it after modification

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Heroku but I'm curious if this is a problem related to enforced nomenclature on main branch.

A while back I could not push my first commit to a new and empty Git repository if my push command was "git push origin master", it started working after I changed it to "git push origin main" so I suspect this could be the issue you're facing.

Sorry I couldn't ask you before I posted this answer if this is your first push, I do not have enough points to post a comment.

Comment: Thank you. If I remember correctly, the origin command should be from the Linux system. My system is windows. This is my first push

Answer (score 0):

This is due to that Heroku has specific python runtimes.
Visit the link to know : [Heroku Supported Runtimes Python](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes)

To solve this issue, simply create a **runtime.txt** file in **root folder** and add **python-3.7.6**

Comment: Python 3.9.7 is supported. In addition, I wrote 3.9.7 on runtime.txt, which still can't solve my problem

Comment: **first remove python from requirements.txt then try, if still faces the issue, try** 
try to add python buildpacks.
Head over to this, and run some commands, first check if heroku has python buildpacks
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#checking-the-python-buildpack-version

Comment: This is a very troublesome problem. I do as you say, but I still can't solve the problem. I always "error: failed to push some refs to" https://git.heroku.com/xxxxxx.git "It's bothering you. Please take another look at it for me. Thank you

Comment: Then the best method is to copy all your files in a new folder and then initialize heroku there and then push. Problem will be solved.
The reason may be due to two branches as specified in error.
Try the above method, it usually works.